# C3.js making line appear dashed

Tags: css, charts, c3

I am using C3.js using two Y axis. I have 2 data series:

```
data: {
        rows: [
        ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
        [90, 120, 300],
        [40, 160, 240],
        [50, 200, 290],
        [120, null, 230],
        [80, null, 300],
        [90, null, 320],
    ],
        regions: {
            'data1': [{'start':0, 'style':'dashed'},],
        }
    }
```

When I run this I get a dashed line and then it graphs null as a dashed line along the x axis. This is not what I want. I want it to stop graphing when the data set is null. If I remove the region I get the functionality I desire but I do not get the dashed line.

Is there a way to get the dashed line without graphing the null values?

Comment: If the values are null, can you exclude them from the data array? (i.e. do a bit of pre-processing beforehand)

Comment: Let me update my data to show you why I think I cant do that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As C3 uses SVG, you can employ CSS selectors to modify the appearance of its elements.

All lines in a C3 chart will have the .c3-line class, take a look: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYJhh.png).

So, we might just add this to our CSS:

```
.c3-line{
  stroke-dasharray: 5,5;
}
```

Here's some documentation for [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray).

[image: Note the classes in the path. We can use them to target the element with CSS]

Comment: This would apply the dash to all lines. Is there a way with c3 to apply a class to a specific series?

Comment: C3 also adds a specific class to each data row. In your example it will be named ".c3-target-data1".

Comment: Check out the "Line Chart with Regions" example: [http://c3js.org/samples/simple_regions.html].  If you don't like dash you can add your own style: `c3-line.lineoff {visibility:hidden;}` Then specify "lineoff" instead.